# »Point of interest« auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Hat jemand eine Idee, wie man ***POI / Point of interest*** kurz und knackig ins Deutsche übersetzen kann?

Es handelt sich um Orte, die vor allem in Navigationssystemen als »Orte vom besonderen Interesse« definiert sind, sprich Sehenswürdigkeiten, Geldautomaten, Polizeireviere etc. Man durchsucht das Navigationssystem nach dem Namen eines POI und nicht nach seiner Adresse.

In allen (deutschsprachigen) Navigationsgeräten, die ich in den Händen hatte, hat man den Begriff *POI* verwendet. Nun befürchte ich (was der Kommentar von Emanuel bestätigt), dass viele Leute mit dem Kürzel nichts anfangen können. Daher die Frage.

Comment: Könntest du kurz erläutern, was das ist, oder ein Beispiel bringen?

Comment: Schon geschehen.

Comment: Wieso »Orte von besonderem Interesse« und nicht einfach "interessante Orte"?

Comment: Weil z.B. ein Polizeirevier kein *interessanter Ort* ist, sondern ein Ort, wo man hinfährt, wenn was Schlimmes passiert ist. Daher fällt es mir so schwer, ein deutsches Äquivalent zu finden.  Weil es sich eben nicht um interessante Orte handelt, sondern um Orte vom Interesse eben. Wenn man sie braucht. *Interessante Orte* ist ein Unterbegriff von *POI*.

Comment: Wenn ich einen Polizist brauche, ist eine Polizeiwache durchaus interessant. Oder, andersherum gesagt, wenn eine Polizeiwache kein interessanter Ort ist, ist der englische Begriff auch unpassend. Genauso für eine Tanke (wenn ich Benzin brauche), ein Restaurant, wenn ich Hunger habe, etc,

Comment: @Robert - ob der englische Begriff passend in diesem Fall ist, sei dahingestellt, weil er sich durchgesetzt hat. Nichtsdestoweniger sind  "interessante Orte" keine Übersetzung, mit der ich zufrieden wäre... Auch wenn's naheliegt.

Comment: "Wichtige Orte" vielleicht? Wobei ich in Frage stellen möchte, dass "McDonalds" ein wichtiger Ort ist. :D

Comment: Maybe "Nennenswerte Orte"? Or "Erwähnenswerte Orte"?

Comment: @Em1 "Wichtige Orte", der ist nicht schlecht. Auch trotz McEinwand ^^ Aber ....... damit würde der Menüpunkt "POI-Suche" zu "Suche nach wichtigen Orten" / "Wichtige Orte finden"? In diesem Zusammenhang klingt es noch sehr holprig.

Comment: Ich finde "(interessante und ) nützliche Orte" eine recht brauchbare Übersetzung, wobei - wie durch die Klammern angedeutet - das "interessante und" auch weggelassen werden könnte. "nützliche Orte" wird bereits relativ häufig verwendet (133.000 google hits).

Comment: _Anziehungspunkt, Anliegen, markanter Ort, Marke, Versorgungspunkt, Sonderpunkt, Sonderort_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia, das zur Übersetzung solcher Begriffe oft hilfreich ist, benutzt ebenfalls [Point of Interest](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_Interest), auch in diversen anderen Sprachen (siehe linke Navigationsleiste dort).

Ich befürchte, ein selbsterfundener Name oder gar eine Abkürzung davon wird es den Leuten, die POI kennen, eher schwerer machen, den Begriff zu verstehen. Die z.B. bei Siemens übliche deutsche Computernomenklatur ([ZRE](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZRE) = Zentrale Recheneinheit statt [CPU](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_%28Begriffskl%C3%A4rung%29)) ist da ein abschreckendes Beispiel.

Answer (score 3):

Im Prinzip gebe ich dirkt Recht. Andererseits ist das natürlich etwas unbefriedigend, da *point of interest* und seine Abkürzung *POI* anders als z.B. *CPU* im Deutschen noch nicht sehr gebräuchlich sind.

Dict.leo.org gibt für das englische Synonym *place of interest* die Übersetzung *interessanter Ort*. Das scheint mir tatsächlich eine ganz brauchbare Übersetzung zu sein. (Einwände dagegen treffen im Grunde auch auf die ursprüngliche englische Wortschöpfung zu.) Noch etwas präziser wäre vielleicht *relevanter Ort*. Und ***relevanter Punkt*** kommt mir noch besser vor.

(Wikipedia hat explizite Richtlinien gegen das Prägen neuer Begriffe, wenn es noch keine passende Übersetzung gibt. Bei Übersetzern ist aber genau das Alltag und völlig korrekt. Irgendwo müssen die neuen Begriffe ja herkommen. Bei Wikipedias Richtlinien geht es weniger um gute Praxis beim Schreiben einer Enzyklopädie als um Probleme bei der Konsensbildung in großen, inhomogenen Gruppen.)

Comment: +1 für "relevanter Punkt"

Answer (score 2):

Also eigentlich würde ich es sinngemäß als `Sehenswürdigkeit` übersetzen. Allerdings lässt sich da dann wohl auch irgendwie darüber streiten, inwiefern McDonald’s oder ein Polizeirevier, Krankenhaus usw. als `Sehenswürdigkeit` zu betrachten sind. Dennoch würde es grundsätzlich zutreffen, da je nachdem was der Anlass ist, auch ein Polizeirevier sich als `sehenswert` oder `sehenswürdig` einstufen lässt. Aber vielleicht mag man es ja lieber als `Ort von Interesse` oder `Orte von Interesse` übersetzen.

Answer (score 1):

Abgesehen davon, daß ich @dirkts antwort sehr gelungen finde:

> interessanter Ort

Wäre eine mögliche und einigermaßen kurze Übersetzung. Auch wenn auch diese Übersetzung immer noch ein wenig komisch riecht, wenn man an Geldautomaten, Polizeistationen oder Friedhöfe denkt.

Answer (score 1):

"Von Interesse" (ohne den Ort).

Das Original ist "Point of Interest", nicht "Place of Interest". Die erwähnten Orte sind oft selbst nicht interessant, aber der Benutzer hat (manchmal, kurzzeitig) ein Interesse an dem Platz.